# How can I display a confirmation alert before redirecting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sweetalert

How can I display a swal fire alert before redirecting?

```
<a :href="`/public/project/sendalert/${project.id}`">{project.first_name+' '+project.last_name}} @click="Alert"</a></strong></span>
    alert() {
            window.Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "Are you sure?"
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'YES!',
              })
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.click event should be put into the  properties.

```
<a @click="Alert">{project.first_name+' '+project.last_name}}</a></strong></span>
```

2.execute the redirect on the confirm action.

```
alert() {
    window.Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "Are you sure?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'YES!',
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            location.href = "...";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: isConfirm is not a function.